# Чем отличается refresh от persist в doctrine 2?

Tags: php, orm, entity, doctrine2

Какая разница будет между

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

и

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->refresh($entity);
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Разница очень большая.

Метод `persist` **выполняет сохранение** объекта в базе данных (точнее не сохранение а его подготовку, физически запись в базу происходит при вызове `flush`)

Метод `refresh` **перечитывает** данные сущности из базы. Если вы изменили какие-либо данные у объекта и не выполнили `persist`, при вызове `refresh` они будут сброшены.

Comment: большое спасибо за подробный ответ